# Android Project sync failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle

My android project was working fine, after 2-3 days I reopened it but project sync failed with below error log. Other projects are working fine.

Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I have done with invalidate/restart IDE, enable/disable offline sync, proxy settings to NONE/Automatic but nothing work

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your cache, the 403 error is sent only when the server detects suspicious evn

Comment: Thanks for your response, i already tried for this but not working.